# Excel 2010, why even a blank xlsm with blank module is causing VBA editor still show the workbook after it close?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Suddenly I have a weird problem with my Excel app.

I've looked the internet and in this site, found similar problem but it seems their problem is because of some codes. While mine, there is no code at all.

At first, after I close my xlsm work file (which has some modules with the code), then I open the VBA editor, sometimes it gives me message box "Out of Memory", sometimes it gives me "catastrophic failure" message box, sometimes there is no message box, but one thing for sure, in the VBA editor it still show the workbook which I've just close.

Strange thing, if I open the Excel app first (which gives me a blank worksehet by default), then I double click my xlsm working file, then close it, then open the VBA editor, there never any message box and in the VBA editor also there is no workbook which I've just close.

So it happen only if I directly open my xlsm working file... or any other xlsm file which has a module, even a blank module.

It doesn't happen if I directly open (by double clicking) an xlsx file.

Curious, I open the Excel app (it gives me a blank worksheet by default), Insert a blank module in VBA editor then save the workbook as Book1.xlsm.

[image]

.
.
.

Then I close the workbook.... and I see that in the VBA editor it still has the Book1.xlsm there.

[image]

.
.
.

Then I just close the Excel app, and open it again. Then I double click the Book1.xlsm.
Close the Book1.xlsm, there is no Book1.xlsm left in the VBA editor.

.
.
.

Then I close the Exel app. I directly double click the Book1.xlsm
Close the Book1.xlsm. Again, there is still Book1.xlsm in the VBA editor.

I've tried to repair the Microsoft Office 2010 via Control Panel ---> Programs.
After it's done, MS Office ask to reboot. So I reboot. Directly double click the Book1.xlsm, close the Book1.xlsm. No joy. VBA editor still show Book1.xlsm left there.

Although I realize that maybe the last resort I need to do is to uninstall MS Office and then reinstall it back, but still I wonder, if anyone here know what cause this kind of problem ? What cause a blank xlsm workbook with a blank module - after it close, the VBA editor still show it ?

Why if I open the Excel app first, then open the xlsm file, the problem does not exist ?

FYI, all the subs in my working xlsm file can still run without problem.

Any kind of explanation would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you check if the Book1.xlsm is selected as an AddIn ? Developer->ExcelAddins, check ticks)

Comment: @tinazmu, nothing is checked in in AddIn. Thank you for asking.